# Eclipse Android Project Error

Tags: android, eclipse

Trying to run my Android App and Eclipse (in Windows 7) is throwing up an error. Yesterday I had no problem so I can't think what I could have done to caus eit. The error message is

```
**Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.**
```

Well, I went to window->view->error log and I found this

```
Warning

While loading class "com.android.sdklib.internal.project.ProjectProperties", thread "Thread[main,6,main]" timed out waiting (5000ms) for thread "Thread[org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler,1,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 [317]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[main,6,main]" is proceeding but "com.android.sdklib.internal.project.ProjectProperties" may not be fully initialized.

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_11.0.0.v201105251008-128486.jar" by thread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler".
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1073)
```

I would like ot add that although the project itself is showing an error no source file or resource has an error.

SO far I have tried:

clean/build (several times)

close eclipse and reopen (several times)

shutdown computer and restart

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Tried again and got the following message in console:

**[2011-08-14 00:40:47 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
[2011-08-14 00:40:47 - MyAppName] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first**

Don't know it cant convert to Dalvik format. The SDK is in the build path.

Comment: This problem usually indicates that you need to include some jar that you use in your build path.

Comment: do other android projects work ?

Comment: @sherif. I tried to run another project and now all Android projects are showing the same error. I can't run any of them.

Comment: @MByD. Thanks, but I am not using any outside jar files. Just the Android SDK and the class files in my project.

Comment: ok then there is a problem with your sdk or with the plugin try to reinstall both shoud do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feels to me something wrong with the SDK. Why dont you uninstall the current Android sdk and install a new version instead.

Answer (score 2):

After much stress and pain and me almost throwing my computer out the window I found the problem is in the debug.keystore file. Although Eclipse gave me no warning of this. After deleting the debug.keystore file I cleaned/build my project.

Eclipse gave the following error.

Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.

[2011-08-14 13:16:42 - MyApp] You must perform a full uninstall of the application.

WARNING: This will remove the application data!

[2011-08-14 13:16:42 - MyApp] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.etc.etc' in a shell.

[2011-08-14 13:16:42 - MyApp] Launch canceled!

I didnt follow the advice but simply renamed my package. It works now. I'm not sure what to do with older packages that I have released onto the Market. It will be difficult to add new versions if I have to rename them to test them on the emulator/my phone.

Comment: The uninstall warning you are getting there is just on the test device (or emulator image) that you are using - the same app can't have two different signatures (debug and release) on the one device.  It will work fine for the market.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your Project in Eclipse and choose Properties. Check in the Java Build Path that you have the Google API's in the Libraries tab. Check the references to them.

Comment: Hmmm... I checked the SDK in the build path (please see my edited question). It says Access rules: 1 rule defined, Forbidden. Presumably this is undesirable, although I dont know how to change it.

Comment: Out of interest, in Eclipse, does your project folder have a little 'a' above it or a 'J' ?

Comment: 'a'. It is an android project. The project  has the dreaded red x, but all source files are fine.I am at the point of thinking about reinstalling eclipse and the sdk.